# combinatorics - recurrence relations

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I tasked with solving the recurrence relation $a_n = 5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2}$ given the initial conditions $a_0 = 1, a_1 = 4$. I do not know how to begin here. However, I know that $$a_2 = 14,$$ $$a_3 = 46,$$ $$a_4 = 146,$$ $$a_5 = 454.$$ What is the pattern here?

Edit: I have explicit instructions to use generating functions, and then extract the coefficients using the GF.

Comment: Start by assuming that a solution is of the form $a_n=r^n$ for some $r \in \Bbb{R}$. Then use that to get a quadratic equation in $r$.

Answer (score 2):

It seem that $a_{n+1}= 3a_n$ for $n\geq 1$ and thus the sequance is geometric....

Prove by induction: Base $n=1,2$ is obivuosly.

Induction step: $n,n-1\to n+1$:

$$ a_{n+1} = 5a_n-6a_{n-1} = 15a_{n-1}-18a_{n-2} = 3(5a_{n-1}-6a_{n-2})= 3a_n$$

Comment: Yey, I go over 50K

Comment: Could you please explain how you wrote $5a_n - 6a_{n-1}=15a_{n-1}-18a_{n-2}$?

Comment: by induction hypothetis $a_n = 3a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-1}=3a_{n-2}$

Comment: This is of no help to you?

Comment: @MariaMazur It might be worth checking the OP's edit. It seems he forgot one restriction of the problem: he needs to use generating functions to solve this (probably a textbook exercise). :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want generating functions, define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, write:

$\begin{align*}
a_{n + 2}
  &= 5 a_{n + 1} - 6 a_n \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 2} z^n
  &= 5 \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n - 6 \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n \\
\frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2}
  &= 5 \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} - 6 A(z)
\end{align*}$

Use the values for $a_0, a_1$, solve as partial fractions:

$\begin{align*}
A(z)
  &= \frac{2}{1 - 3 z} - \frac{1}{1 - 2 z} \\
a_n
  &= [z^n] A(z) \\
  &= 2 \cdot 3^n - 2^n
\end{align*}$